# Write a CSV file to ADLS container from DataBricks

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-lake

Have given Public access to the container as well as storage account has full access.
Using scope and key to read the data.
I can able to read the data but not able to write. Facing below error.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4764.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:711)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:711)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:711)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:235)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor526.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 129.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 129.0 (TID 1872, localhost, executor driver): shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2109)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.getAncestor(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2665)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.create(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1743)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.create(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.directory.DirectoryAtomicCommitProtocol.newTaskTempFileAbsPath(DirectoryAtomicCommitProtocol.scala:121)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.directory.DirectoryAtomicCommitProtocol.newTaskTempFile(DirectoryAtomicCommitProtocol.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1526)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:113)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$WrappingIterator.hasNext(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:133)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2087)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The specified resource does not exist.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:178)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:109)
    ... 24 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2355)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2343)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2342)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2342)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2574)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2522)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2510)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2109)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.getAncestor(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2665)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.create(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1743)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.create(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.directory.DirectoryAtomicCommitProtocol.newTaskTempFileAbsPath(DirectoryAtomicCommitProtocol.scala:121)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.directory.DirectoryAtomicCommitProtocol.newTaskTempFile(DirectoryAtomicCommitProtocol.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1526)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:113)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$WrappingIterator.hasNext(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:133)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2087)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The specified resource does not exist.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:178)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:109)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Hi @Raja Sabarish, Can you please edit your question along with  the code how  you  writing  csv file to container.